# export oracle data block to excel

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298648/oracle-to-excel-pl-sql-export-procedure) I try to export my data to Excel, after several challenge now my problem is it seems work well but I can not see the exported excel file!!!!

(first solution's http://www.protalk.in/oracle/plsql-tips-package-for-exporting-data-to-excel/ )

I use '/' for my directory.

please help me. where is the exported file? what else should  I do? I use oracle 6.

Comment: Please post did you solve your problem or not?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I think right but...Can you run this query and tell me the result(especially what does column "value" holds?):

```
select * 
from v$parameter
where name='utl_file_dir'
```

Comment: value of 'utl_file_dir' is '/' thats all! :(

Comment: what does it mean "I use '/' for my directory."?? can you write path ,instead of '/',  which indicates some folder that you can access??

Comment: if I do I receive error Ora-29280! I dont think it's a correct way.help plz :(

Comment: create directory dir_name as 'path_to_your_folder';

and then indicate dir_name  instead of '/'..try

Comment: I asked DBA still under progress, but it is so funny isnt it.one more this if we chose '/' our file will go where?

Comment: In windows I don't know where will it go:D but in linux maybe it will go in a root directory(not sure):)

Comment: I can not use this way, help me in another way plzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz

Comment: I still have problem plz help me:((