# Writing in ExcelSheet using UTL_FILE package in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have no problem in writing data in excel sheet which is stored in some predefined directory.

Now I have 10 sets of data and for each set I have to create 10 seperate excel sheet.
But what I want is to create Workbook conating sheet1,sheet2,. Sheet10. Which will have all 10 sets of record. If my question is not clear let me know.

I'm using PL/SQL Oracle 9i

My Code which will write to excel for one set of data. What if I have more set of data and I don't want to have multiple excel sheet instead I want one workbook with diff sheet.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_ORACLE_EXCEL(I_FILE_NAME    IN VARCHAR2) AS

  FILENAME  UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
  FILENAME1 VARCHAR2(1000);
  CURSOR C1 IS
    SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE;
  VARC1 C1%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN

  FILENAME1   := 'TEST_' || I_FILE_NAME || '_' || SYSDATE || '.CSV';

  FILENAME    := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('TEMP_DIR', FILENAME1, 'W');

  /* THIS WILL CREATE THE HEADING IN EXCEL SHEET */
    UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(FILENAME,
                   'HEADER1' || ',' || 'HEADER2' || ',' || 'HEADER3' || ',' ||
                    'HEADER4' || ',' || 'HEADER5');
  OPEN C1;
  LOOP
    FETCH C1
       INTO VARC1;
    EXIT WHEN C1%NOTFOUND;
     /*  THIS WILL PRINT THE RECORDS IN EXCEL SHEET AS PER THE QUERY IN CURSOR */
    UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(FILENAME,
                      '"' || VARC1.COL1 || '"' || ' ,' || '"' ||
                      VARC1.COL2 || '"' || ' ,' || '"' ||
                      VARC1.COL3 || '"' || ' ,' || '"' ||
                      VARC1.COL4 || '"' || ' ,' || '"' ||
                      VARC1.COL5|| '"');


  END LOOP;

  UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(FILENAME);

END SP_ORACLE_EXCEL;
```

Comment: how do you write xls files with UTL_FILE? Can you share with us?

Comment: @florin code shared.. :)

Comment: OK, that is a csv file, not xls. It is a flat text file, that MS Excel knows to read. in csv, obvious, you can't have sheets. xls is more complicated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no ready-to-use implementation that I'm aware of.

Excel files (.xslx) since '07 are actually zip archives containing separate xml files for each worksheet.

The XML schema they're using is [pretty straight forward](http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main). You'd have to use Java to create the folders and do the zip compression in order to write such files.

Comment: The link you posted no longer works.  This [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd979954(v=office.12).aspx) to MSDN should be the same thing though.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with the open source [PL/SQL ExcelDocumentType](http://sourceforge.net/projects/exceldoctype/).  (Although I haven't tried it on 9i.)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution to this problem recently posted here on SO ([Create an Excel File (.xlsx) using PL/SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41299024/create-an-excel-file-xlsx-using-pl-sqla)).

i used a package called `as_xlsx` created by Anton Scheffer, [Create an Excel-file with PL/SQL](https://technology.amis.nl/2011/02/19/create-an-excel-file-with-plsql/) and did a few modifications to the package
so it creates multiple sheets inside a single Excel Workbook by putting it through a Loop.

Hope this helps!