# How to share an Excel file that has a SQL Query Connection

Tags: sql, excel, sqlconnection, file-sharing

I am trying to share a file containing a table of information pulled from an external SQL query connection. It works fine for me as I have the connections set up on my PC but when I send the file out, it asks for connection credentials. I could go to each PC and enter the credentials but would prefer the end users to open up the file and use it without having to enter any credentials and would like them to be able to refresh the data as and when needed.

How would I set this up or is it even possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Put the file in a place that's accessible to everyone who needs it.

Comment: It's saved on the network that everyone has access to.

Comment: If the receivers of the document should not have connection to the database, or can not establish a connection due to technical limitations, best way to do this is generating and Excel-Document in the database and spread this one. For Oracle, there are some solutions available (f.e. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298648/oracle-to-excel-pl-sql-export-procedure/477276#477276) which require more or less coding. Or, if the documents are more complex (formulas, charts, conditional-formattings, etc.) you may consider using a commercial tool like smaxt.com or others ...

Answer (score 0):

Your connection string should be using Windows Authentication, and the local user must be a member of a domain group that has the privileges to run the query on SQL Server.

If you go to Connection Properties, open the connection, and click on Definition, the Integrated Security tag should be set to SSPI.